# How to install "factoextra" in R?

Tags: r, factoextra

I am using R version `3.0.3`. while running

```
library(devtools)
install_github("kassambara/factoextra")
```

Iam getting below error:

```
Downloading github repo kassambara/factoextra@master
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Failed to connect to api.github.com port 443: Timed out
```

Can anyone please tell me how to install this package?

Comment: @Pascal the OS has nothing to do with timeout problems. The proxy *could* be responsible if it's set to block github. Such blocks are set at the network's firewall or router though and disabling the proxy may not help. \

Comment: This question is borderline out-of-topic. This is about network connectivity, not programming

Comment: @Pascal the inaccuracy of the comment notwithstanding, this is a *connectivity* issue, not an installation failure. A network block on the router or firewall will affect both OSs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you are behind a proxy that blocks https or something like that. Just retry from another location and see if that fixes the issue. Or talk to your local system administrator and fix the issue.

It could also be a temporary github problem, in which case retrying at a later moment will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks all for your support. Finally i installed "factoextra".

Comment: What was the issue? If my answer was correct, please mark it as such by pressing the tick mark to the left of my answer.